# Filter layered navigations options/items through ajax

Tags: layered-navigation

I want to get the available options/items of a layered navigation, but I cannot find out how to achieve this.

Basically, I want to know what filters with items are available, when I set some filters, without having a product collection. For example: 
I send an request saying size L categories Tshirts
and get returned the colors red and blue are availble, but not the color black.

I just cannot find, where the options of my attributes are being filtered.

I hope I could make myself clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a solution, probably not the best as it includes some overhead, but it only needs very few lines of code:

You can get all items by initialising a filter Block:

```
$items = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
```

What I didn't know was how to filter then the returned items. This actually is done by the block itself.
So you can just send an reqeust like ?attributecode=value to your controller that creates the block and it returns now only the filtered items.